# C++ Global Variable vs Java instance variable

Tags: java, c++, oop

I have a question about global variables in C++.  I'm coming from a Java background where you can have an instance variable declared and used like so:

Example.java

```
class Example
{
   int x;

   doSomththing()
   {
      x = 1;
   }

   doSomethingElse()
   {
      x = 2;
   }
}
```

My question is, in C++ if i do something similar, would that be classified as a global variable or an instance variable.  Observe my C++ example to clarify:

Example.h

```
class Example{

public:
void do_something();
void do_somethingElse();

private:
int x;

};
```

Example.cpp

```
#include Example.h

void Example::do_something()
{
    x = 1;
}

void Example::do_somethingElse()
{
    x = 2;
}
```

So in the C++ example, is x a global or an instance variable?  If its not a global, then how can x be properly defined as a global?

Comment: Create two instances of your `Example` class in C++ and try modifying its state one by one, check the value of `x` of both and you will get your answer. Hint: try doing the same exercise but now using `static` keyword.

Comment: Have you tried accessing it globally?

Comment: **Why** do you think it should be a global variable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you should know that your Java example cannot be translated 1:1 to C++ because C++ doesn't know **package-private accessibility** (in fact, C++ doesn't really have packages at the language level, and a proposal to add them to the language didn't make it into C++11). Your class `Example` as well as its `x` field and methods are package-private, which means that they are hidden from any code outside of the package.

C++ only knows `public`, `protected` and `private`, which largely (but not fully!) correspond to their Java equivalents, but it also knows **friend** functions and classes, which can sometimes be used to achieve results similar to package-private accessibility.

Apart from this accessibility issue, the `x` variable in your C++ example is the same as in your Java example, i.e. it is an instance variable, with separate values in every instance of the class.

Global variables are possible in C++, but as you may already know, they are *usually* bad design. Imagine this complete C++ program:

```
int x; // global variable, usually bad

int main()
{
  x = 123;
}
```

Does this mean that Java prevents such bad design, however? No, it does not. It shields you from some surprising dangerous low-level aspects which come with global variables in C++ (read more about the [static initialization order fiasco](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/static-init-order.html) for details), but not from the bad high-level aspects. A **public static variable which is not final** is much like an ordinary global variable in C++.

Take this Java code, for example:

```
public class Example {
    public static int x; // hardly better than a global variable in C++
}
```

This is hardly better than a "real" global variable in C++. Every piece of code in your whole program can access it, which increases tight coupling and affects testability.

Here's another example for a bad global variable in disguise in Java:

```
public class Singleton {
    private static final Singleton INSTANCE = new Singleton();

    private int x; // global variable in disguise

    private Singleton() {
    }

    public static Singleton getInstance() {
        return INSTANCE;
    }

    public int getX() {
        return x;
    }

    public void setX(int newX) {
        x = newX;
    }
}
```

(Yes, the Singleton design pattern *is* nothing more than a glorified global variable in 99% of all cases I've ever seen in any piece of code.)

The point is: technically Java doesn't feature global variables like C++, but it's not hard to emulate their behaviour and defects, and then they are exactly as bad (minus some low-level initialization issues present in C++). They just look nicer and "cleaner" with all the class stuff around them, especially to beginners.

By the way, you can implement the Singleton (anti) pattern in C++ as well, and it is typically not much more than a glorified global variable there as well:

```
class Singleton
{
private:
    static Singleton *instance;
    int x; // global variable in disguise
    Singleton() : x(0) {}
public:
    static Singleton &instance()
    {
        // ignoring any concurrency issues for
        // simplicity's sake, don't try this at
        // home

        if (instance == nullptr)
        {
            instance = new Singleton;
        }
        return *instance;
    }

    void setX(int newX) { x = newX; }
    int getX() const { return x; }
};
```

You can also create a simpler global variable in disguise with the combination of `static`, `public` and non-`const`, just like in Java:

```
class Example
{
public:
    static int x; // global variable in disguise
};
```

---

Just to make this very clear: **`static` is not evil.** But you have to know where to apply it, and you have to realise that the combination of `public`, `static` and non-`final`/non-`const` is usually a (well-intended, but short-sighted) replacement for "real" global variables, in Java as well as in C++.

Answer (score 3):

As x is not the same if you create a new instance of Example, it is a instance variable. If you want x to be shared between all instances of Example, you should define it as `static`

Comment: Note that you should not answer a question with another question. Do not doubt of your answers.

Answer (score 1):

Just like in Java or C#, x is also an instance variable.  For better or for worse, C++ allows variables outside of a class definition, such as follows:

```
class Example{

public:
    void do_something();
    void do_somethingElse();

private:
    int x;
};
```

Example.cpp

```
#include Example.h

static int g_value = 17;
extern int g_another_value;

void Example::do_something()
{
    x = g_value + g_another_value + 1;
}

void Example::do_somethingElse()
{
    x = g_value - g_another_value + 2;
}
```

OtherCode.cpp

```
int g_another_value = 31;
// other code
```

In this case, the *static* keyword will allow the scope to only this file, however removing static, and re-declaring the variable in other cpp files preceeded by the keyword *extern* will allow the compiler to be happy and the linker will resolve the variable.

Hope this helps.

Comment: @SilverBackApe: Mind that in C++, the `static` keyword is quite overloaded, i.e. it has a lot of different meanings depending on where you put it. It can appear inside of a function definition, in a class definition or outside of any function or class definition. In a "perfect" language you would have three different keywords for that, but when C++ was invented it was important not to invent too many new keywords and to be compatible with old C code as well, which is why we have this arguably confusing situation today. I suggest you search on Google for the different meanings of `static`.

Answer (score 1):

A global variable is declared in C/C++ by just putting it at the top level, outside any class statement, something which is not possible in Java.

```
int y;
```

The variable `x` in your example is clearly an instance variable. Apart from the visibility (private vs. package) it is exactly equivalent to `x` in your Java example.